# Can I pass a $scope variable from one function to another function inside the controller? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters

is it possible to pass a $scope variable to another function inside the controller?

the first function is a POST request which included the id.

the second function is a ng-click function which needs the $scope.id variable.

is there a way to pass them ? maybe as a global variable or can i write the $scope.id in the parameter list from the second function.

the second approach is that I pass the parameter in my view with ng-click = "getResult({{id}}, r.id)"

this is my controller:

```
    .controller('HomeController',
['$scope', '$rootScope', 'SendJmeterFile', 'NotificationPollService', 'GetResultFile',
function ($scope, $rootScope, SendJmeterFile , NotificationPollService, GetResultFile) {

    $scope.upload = function() {

        $scope.dataTable = false;
        $scope.id = 0;
        $scope.results = "";
        var customArtifacts = "";
        var testDataBase = "";

        if($scope.jmeterFile.customArtifact == undefined){
            customArtifacts = null;
        } else {customArtifacts = $scope.jmeterFile.customArtifact.base64}

        if($scope.jmeterFile.testDataBase == undefined){
            testDataBase = null;
        } else {testDataBase = $scope.jmeterFile.testDataBase.base64}

        SendJmeterFile.upload($scope.jmeterFile.jmeter.base64, customArtifacts, $scope.jmeterFile.customProperties, $scope.jmeterFile.instanceConfiguration, $scope.jmeterFile.instances, $scope.jmeterFile.providerID, testDataBase)
            .then(function(data) {
                alert("Daten erfolgreich verschickt!");
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.data.id);
                $scope.dataTable = false;
                $scope.id = data.data.id;
                var poller = new NotificationPollService($scope.id);
                poller.promise.then(onSuccess, onError, onNotify);

                function onSuccess(data) {
                    // data.status == "DONE"
                    console.log("done controller" + data);
                    $scope.dataTable = true;
                    $scope.results = data.data.results;
                };

                function onError(data) {
                // data.status == "ERROR"
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log("error controller" + data);
                    $scope.dataTable = false;
                };

                function onNotify(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                // data.status == "TEST" || data.status == "SETUP"
                    console.log("test/setup controller" + data);
                    $scope.dataTable = false;
                };

            });
            }, function(data) {
                alert("Fehler!");
                console.log("else controller" + data);
                $scope.dataTable = false;
            };  

    $scope.getResult = function() {

        GetResultFile.getResult(id, rid)
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log("Download erfolgreich");
            console.log("data.status");
        });
    }, function(data) {
        console.log("Download ERROR!");
        console.log(data.status);
    };
```

EDIT

i try it with this approach:

```
$scope.getResult = function(rid) {

        GetResultFile.getResult($scope.id, rid)
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log("Download erfolgreich");
            console.log("data.status");
        });
    }, function(data) {
        console.log("Download ERROR!");
        console.log(data.status);
    };
```

this is the call in my view from $scope.upload:

```
<span ng-show="dataTable">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in results">
            <td><a ng-click="getResult(r.id)" download>{{r.results.name}}</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</span>
```

this is from the $scope.getResult:

```
<span ng-show="dataTable">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in results">
            <td><a ng-click="getResult(r.id)" download>{{r.results.name}}</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</span>
```

Comment: `$scope` is globally hoisted in the controller. You can also by default access the parent `$scope` within a child controller. It's injected into the controller -- there's no need to pass it as a function param.

Comment: can you look at my controller i post under my question ?

can i use the $scope.id in my second function GetResultFile ?

Comment: Please edit your question, you posted that as an answer

Comment: @Kai, you're assinging `id` to scope `$scope.id` inside `$scope.upload`, so it should be called before `$scope.getResult`

Comment: @Maximus ah i see, maybe i pass the $scope.id in the parameter list from GetResultFile, like this : GetResultFile.getResult($scope.id, rid)

Comment: how is `$scope.upload` and `$scope.getResult` called?

Comment: @Maximus's answer below is correct, one thing to note, when you think of $scope within a controller (or directive for that matter) treat it in the same way you would treat `this` . https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/ this link talks about why Angular has tried to move people over to the controller as syntax as this removes the confusion of $scope

Comment: @Maximus thank you, it works !

Comment: @Kai, great, you can accept my answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to pass a $scope variable to another function inside
>   the controller ?

`$scope` is injected as a parameter to the controller function, so all functions defined inside the controller have access to the `$scope` through closure

```
.controller('mycontroller', function($scope) {

    function makesPostRequest() {
       console.log($scope);
    }

    $scope.getResult = function(params) {
       console.log($scope);
    }

});
```

So, given your example, this should do it:

```
$scope.getResult = function (rid) {
    GetResultFile.getResult($scope.id, rid)
                            ^^^^^^^^^
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log("Download erfolgreich");
            console.log("data.status");
        }, function (data) {
            console.log("Download ERROR!");
            console.log(data.status);
        })
};
```

Comment: hi, 

i have set my the $scope.id in my first function inside a service function and want to pass the id to the second service function ( which is a ng-click function), can you check my controller I post under my question ?

thank you

Comment: sorry, i dont know how to explain it :D

Comment: @Kai, how is `$scope.upload` and `$scope.getResult` called?

Comment: @Maximus $scope.upload is a submit button to post a test request and $scope.getResult is a ng-click event if the user want to download a result file ( the block with the result files is only show, if the test request is succeed)

Comment: this should work `GetResultFile.getResult($scope.id, rid)`, put a `console.log($scope.id)`, what does it ouput?

Comment: @Maximus i try it and tell you if it succeed or failed, thanks first for your help !

Comment: @Kai, sure, if it works, you can accept my answer then. By the way, you have syntax error (second function should be passed inside `then`) in your `getResult` example, see my updated answer.

Comment: @Maximus thank you for the tip, i will test it now, i have to start all the microservice :)